# AngularJS 1.5.2 directive with ng-class not changing class

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input 
      name="email" 
      ng-model="email" 
      check-input 
      ng-class="{
        'input-neutral': myForm.email.$error.checkEmail === 'empty',
        'input-valid': myForm.email.$error.checkEmail === 'valid', 
        'input-invalid': myForm.email.$error.checkEmail === 'invalid'}
      ">
  </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
input {
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.input-neutral {
  border-color: lightblue;
}
.input-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
.input-valid {
  border-color: lime;
}
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]);

app.directive('checkInput', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.checkEmail = function(modelVal, viewVal) {
        if (viewVal) {
          var regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
          var isValid = regex.test(viewVal);
          if(isValid)
            return 'valid';
          return 'invalid';
        }
        return 'empty';
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

So what I'm trying to do is when the input field is empty have the border as `lightblue`, when the input field is filled incorrectly have the border `red` and when the input matches the regex (which is an email address for example `a@b.c`) have the border `lime`.

The border doesn't even turn `lightblue`?

---

### Finished code

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form">
    <input name="email" ng-model="email" check-input="email" ci-empty-class="input-empty" ci-invalid-class="input-invalid" ci-valid-class="input-valid">
    <input name="password" ng-model="password" check-input="password" ci-empty-class="input-empty" ci-invalid-class="input-invalid" ci-valid-class="input-valid">
  </form>
</div>
```

css:

```
input {
  border: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.input-empty {
  border-color: lightblue;
}
.input-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
.input-valid {
  border-color: lightgreen;
}
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {}]);

app.directive('checkInput', [function() {
  var emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
  var passwordRegex  = /^.{3,}$/;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
      if (attr.ciEmptyClass) { // three states; empty, invalid, valid
        // initial class
        el.toggleClass(attr.ciEmptyClass, true);
        // update on input change
        el.on('keyup change', function() {
          if (ctrl.$viewValue) { // value in input exists
            var isValid;
            if(attr.checkInput === 'email')
              isValid = emailRegex.test(ctrl.$viewValue);
            if(attr.checkInput === 'password')
              isValid = passwordRegex.test(ctrl.$viewValue);
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciValidClass, isValid);
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciInvalidClass, !isValid);
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciEmptyClass, false);
          } else { // value in input does not exist
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciValidClass, false);
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciInvalidClass, false);
            el.toggleClass(attr.ciEmptyClass, true);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: You don't feel the inbuilt html5 email validation that angular can utilize with the ngMessages directive is adequate?

Comment: @sjm Tbh I'm going to be using this for more than regex directed at email so no, html5 email validation won't do it.

Comment: Don't validators return true/false? If it's not valid then `myForm.email.$error.checkEmail` will be true and `myForm.email.$error.checkEmail` won't even be present if it's valid.

Comment: @Lex You are right re-read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues with you code, so I'm guessing its not complete,  interms of the directive structure you can't return a value from a directive and expect to use it how you've shown instead I would set my element directive template(if you want to assign classes to each individual input) like so:

```
<input name="email" ng-model="email" check-input ci-empty-class="input-neutral" ci-valid-class="input-valid" ci-invalid-class="input-invalid">
```

Then in your directive set the class based on the attr you've added i.e.

```
if(isValid){
   el.addClass(attr.ciInvalidClass);
}else{
   el.addClass(attr.ciValidClass);
}
```

Comment: Indeed I'm learns the nitty ropes atm. Hah I actually thought of doing what you were thinking but then I thought, "maybe angular has this inbuilt". I'll try it this way and get back!